# sprintf() is giving Access Violation Error in VS2008

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am facing issue while running an application through `VS2008`. I have debugged the code and found that issue is with `sprintf()`. I am getting the following error

> Unhandled exception at 0x005251d2 in clarify.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading >location 0xffffffd4.

while executing the below line

```
static char buf[512]; 
char time_buf[100];

sprintf(buf, 
"EVENT_TIME %5.2f DOING 'LOGIN EVENT' on 'Session Login' LEVEL 1 \n AT %s \n\n",
seconds, time_buf);
```

I have tried `_snprintf()` also but facing the same issue.

Comment: please post relevant code. (e.g. declaration of buf and time_buf)

Comment: So what does the debugger say the values of `buf`, `seconds`, and `time_buf` are?  One or more of them probably aren't quite right.  I'll bet it's `time_buf`.

Comment: Declarations are given below...static char buf[512];  
char            time_buf[100];  Values of time_buf and seconds are corrects.. time_buf is giving the time of the machine.. before executing this line .. buf is containing valid string

Comment: more code. :) Are all strings definitely terminated?

Comment: @Nikhil: maybe you can post a stacktrace from when the debugger catches the exception. In particular a stacktrace that shows the arguments passed to `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the seconds floating point type?
Why don't you divide it in smaller parts?
first try:

```
sprintf(buf, "test");
```

then:

```
sprintf(buf, "test %s", time_buf);
```

then:

```
sprintf(buf, "test %5.2", seconds);
```

Comment: One more thing i m observing.. before the call to the sprintf() .. buf is containing string.. but that string is having garbage characters at the end.. Can this be the cause??

Comment: Why don't you answer my question instead?
And no, it doesn't matter, buf is not initialized, so it can contain garbage characters.

Comment: Yes secinds is floating point type and I tried with dividing it in different parts.. still facing same issue... :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your case is using an array to write from.

Debugging shows that your Code will do nothing else than writing only the first element of `time_buf` to `buf` and the rest of the content will just be ignored.

Eclipse is ignoring this fact and does not give me any kind of warning or error but maybe VS got some other restrictions for this case.

You could do something like

```
char buf[100];
char* temp;
temp = "--> Some Content <--";

sprintf(buf, "%s", temp);
```

This will copy the full content to the buffer, but its up to you if you can use that in your case.